# How to execute Javascript with Codeception and get the returned values

Tags: selenium, codeception

Is there any way of making this work ?

```
    $I->amOnPage('/');

    $I->wait(2);

    $I->executeJS('
        var theCookies = document.cookie.split(\';\');
        var aString = \'\';
        for (var i = 1 ; i <= theCookies.length; i++) {
            aString += i + \' \' + theCookies[i-1] + "\n";
        }
        return aString;
    ');
```

Besides the fact that I get an error thrown, would something like this be possible?

Comment: try $I->executeJS('return document.cookie.split(\';\')')

Comment: @Murthi Hey this actually works, but it does not show me any 3rd party cookies, ot at least not everything that i can see in the browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's documented here: https://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver

### executeJS

Executes custom JavaScript.

This example uses jQuery to get a value and assigns that value to a PHP variable:

```
$myVar = $I->executeJS('return $("#myField").val()');

// additional arguments can be passed as array
// Example shows `Hello World` alert:
$I->executeJS("window.alert(arguments[0])", ['Hello world']);
```